# Git branch contains - legacy and consistency

Tags: git, version-control, command-line-arguments

Git seems to treat the `git branch` command's `--contains`, `--merge`, and `--no-merge` options inconsistently.

This question may be better served on the [Git mailing list](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitCommunity), but it may be useful to place it here as well.

I have found that specifying multiple `--contains` options to the `git branch` command like this:

```
git branch --contains <hash1> --contains <hash2>
```

is treated as an **or** operation where branches that contain either `<hash1>` or `<hash2>` are printed.

However, specifying multiple `--merged` or `--no-merged` options to the `git branch` command like this:

```
git branch --merged <hash1> --merged <hash2>
```

ignores `<hash1>` and prints only the branches merged into `<hash2>`, meaning that it is the same as if you executed:

```
git branch --merged <hash2>
```

This was confirmed on Git versions 1.8 and 2.10 (which was built from source).

Considering that the documentation specifies a particular format of these commands and yet Git allows what I can only assume is their *misuse*, **can anyone tell me if these *features* would be useful in some edge case I'm not considering?**

---

*I would have expected that specifying multiple `--contains` options being treated as an **and** operation would be more useful than treating it as an **or** which can be achieved through concatenation of successive invocations of the command.*

---

***Side note***: The `git branch` command seems to still support the old form of the `--contains` command, which was `--with` even though documentation no longer makes any mention of it.

Answer (score 0):

For now, it’s not possible. `git branch --contains SHA` is only available for a certain commit.

Multiple `--contains` in a `git branch` command will output all the branches in any of a commit (it does **or** operation).

Comment: Perhaps my question wasn't clear. Would altering the behaviour of Git when multiple `--contains` options have an adverse affect on any existing git functionality? I've also updated my question in an attempt to make it more clear.

Comment: No, as you tested, if you use multiple `--contains`, the result will contains all the branches of any one commit containing.